# Vim doesn't copy text into custom registers

Tags: vim, copy-paste

I'm trying to copy some boilerplate code into a custom register in vim, so I can easily paste it when I need it. The code I am trying to copy, in Golang is simply

```
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    return
}
```

Now I understand that there are custom registers in vim that can be accessed by letter names.

I am trying to copy this piece of code into the register `e` with following command after having select the text in visual mode.

```
:<,>"ey
```

When I try to paste from the register with `:"ep`, nothing happens. When I try to see what is the register `e`, using `:reg "e`, I get

```
Type Name Content
l    ""        ^J
```

which is not what I would expect.

I've also tried

```
:<,>"eyy
```

to the same effect.

My .vimrc is

```
:set nu
:set tabstop=4
:set showmatch
:colorscheme koehler
:set expandtab
:set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Best wishes,

Answer (score 1):

You are using normal mode and visual mode commands in command-line mode, which can't possibly be expected to work:

```
:<,>"ey
:<,>"eyy
:"ep
```

Either you use those commands in the correct mode…

- Visual mode:

  ```
  v{motion}"ey
  ```
- Normal mode

  ```
  "eyy
  "ep
  ```

or you use their command-line mode equivalent…

- Command-line mode:

  ```
  :'<,'>y e<CR>
  :y e<CR>
  :put=@e<CR>
  ```

Reference:

```
:help vim-modes
:help y
:help v_y
:help p
:help :y
:help :put
```

By the way, `:reg "e` is also incorrect: it should be `:reg e`, as per `:help :reg`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that to me.